# How to set initial React functional component state in test?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I need to run a specific function of a functional React component from another component. That function relies on a specific state property. I need to set it in my test for the function in order to run.

Is that possible somehow? I use Jest, enzyme, react-dom.

Comment: Ciao, is there any relations between components? I mean who is the paren of who? Maybe you could post some line codes just to let me undestand. Thanks :)

Comment: No, at least without mocking `useState`. Since it's supposed to get initial state it relies on somehow, it needs to get it this way. Consider explaining your case in details.